# Chapter styling: header style and chapter number in pages

Tags: header-footer, numbering

I am trying to replicate two chapter configurations I saw looking for templates for my thesis, first a sort of Bjornstrup style ([source](http://132.248.9.195/ptd2023/junio/0841832/Index.html)):

[image]

And second, I'd like to put the chapter number on each chapter page, like this ([source](https://files.nijho.lt/thesis.pdf)):
[image]

Comment: This looks like a job for the `fancyhdr` package. Be sure to get its documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format the chapter title with [`titlesec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) and the header and the chapter number with [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Here's an example in which the chapter title looks like this:

[image]

and the header of another page looks like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
    {\bfseries\LARGE}%
    {\hfill\itshape\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont\thechapter}%
    {0pt}%
    {\makebox[0pt][l]{\rule[-.2\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{1pt}}\MakeUppercase}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\scshape\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\newcommand*{\pagenumberinmargin}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, x=\dimexpr1in+\oddsidemargin]
        \fill[black!80] (1,-1) -- (1,-2) {[rounded corners] -- (.5,-2) -- (.5,-1)} -- cycle;
        \node[white] at (.65,-1.5) {\LARGE\bfseries\thechapter};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage\pagenumberinmargin}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introducción}
\section{Preface}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```